# Norm of vector with entries sent to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have a vector $x $ sampled uniformly at random from the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$, with $n+1$ being an even number. Let's now assume I have a vector $y$ with the same dimension of $x$ whose first $\frac{n+1} 2$ entries are the same of $x$, and the other ones are set to zero. 
What is the expected norm of $y$, i.e.

$$
\mathbb{E}[ \| y \|_2]=?
$$

In other words, 
$$
\mathbb{E} [ \sqrt{ x_i^2 + \dots + x_{\frac{n+1}2}}]$$

the natural answer which would pop up to my mind is that it would be equal to $\frac{\|x\|} {\sqrt 2}$, but the argument breaks down because to do it I have to move the expected value under the square root.

Comment: What do you mean by "expected norm?"

Comment: I mean the expected euclidean norm $\mathbb{E}[ \| y \|_2]$. Thank you for the pointer, I'm editing the question.

Comment: Without knowing the distribution, it is meaningless to speak of an expected value.

Comment: x is a vector sampled uniformly at random from the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to solve this problem.  First, uniformly distributed points $\sigma$ on $S^n$ can be generated by first generating a standard Gaussian random vector $X$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and then rescaling it to give $\sigma=X/\|X\|$.  This business of zeroizing $k$ of the components can be similarly generated by picking a pair of Gaussian vectors, $Y$ from $\mathbb R^k$ and $Z$ from $\mathbb R^{n+1-k}$, and setting your new random quantity  $\tau=Z/\sqrt{\|Y\|^2+\|Z\|^2}$.  The square of the quantity you are interested in has the distribution of $\|Z\|^2/(\|Y\|^2+\|Z\|^2)$.  This is well-known to statisticians to have a so-called Beta distribution, with parameters $((n+1-k)/2,k/2)$.  You want the expectation of the square root of such a variate.

That is, your answer is given by a Beta integral.  The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) is long, but has all the needed ingredients.  It's possible to make algebra mistakes, but I think the answer is $$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+1/2)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)}{\Gamma(\alpha}$$
where $\alpha=(n+1-k)/2$ and $\beta=k/2$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! 
I did the computations again and I get, as an answer, your reciprocal (i.e. 1/(your answer)).
It actually makes more sense, since for large numbers you answer is a value larger then $1$, which cannot be possible. 

Does it make sense to you?

Thank you!

Comment: I got mixed up; you must be right.  I will edit my answer.